# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop after power failure

Tags: login

All of a sudden my 18.04 Ubuntu install started to go into a login loop, after a power failure. Presented with the login screen, I enter the correct credentials and it shows as if it tries to login into the GUI but then falls back into the log in screen. This goes on into an endless loop.

What’s going on? How can I find out what it the culprit?

The system is a TR1950x with 3x nVidia 1080ti GPUs.

Comment: Can you successfully log in to a non-desktop session?

Comment: @OrganicMarble By alt shift F2 at the login splash screen?

Comment: Yeah, whatever the key combo is these days...on my 18.04 LXDE system it's ctrl-alt-f1

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes!

Comment: OK, so your system is not fundamentally broken, just the process of starting the desktop. Something got corrupted when the power cut.  I had to deal with this a while back and I think I looked through the syslog to find what was not starting.